# How can I load one google spreadsheet cell with a value obtained from a remote JSON request?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to populate a google spreadsheed cell with values that I obtain by making JSON HTTP requests to other servers.

If this can be done on schedule even better but even I can trigger this using a simple button on the spreadsheet is ok.

Example of url: https://review.openstack.org/changes/621517 which return a JSON object, and I want to save the status attribute in one cell.

I don't want to write a local script that does this update and updates the spreadsheet as I prefer to make this part of the spreadsheet itself via **Script Editor**.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` ?

Answer (score 1):

For your example, the following should return `NEW`:

```
=substitute(REGEXEXTRACT(index(IMPORTDATA("https://review.openstack.org/changes/621517"),10,1),""".*?"""),"""","")
```